# Layout Inflater Mock issue

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric

I'm trying test a method with layourInflater but I'm getting a null pointer at the line

```
when(LayoutInflater.from(context)).thenReturn(layoutInflaterMock);
```

the method that I'm trying to test looks like this:

```
publc View method(RoomInfoAdapter.FacilityRoomInfoViewHolder holder) {

        View linearLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.some, holder.getParentLayout(), false);
        TextView label = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.label);
        TextView textView = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.type_value);
....
}
```

And my test class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({LayoutInflater.class})
@Config(sdk = 23, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
public class Test {

    @Mock
    private Context context;

    @Mock
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflaterMock;

@Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        context = RuntimeEnvironment.application;
....
    }

@Test
    public void test() {

        when(LayoutInflater.from(context)).thenReturn(layoutInflaterMock);
   ....
    }
```

I was trying to follow this answer:
[How to unit test this line of LayoutInflater.from() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833687/how-to-unit-test-this-line-of-layoutinflater-from-in-android)

But It's not working.

Edit: Now I'm getting:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
>   when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
>   For example:
>       when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Is it even possible to do `when(LayoutInflater.from(context)).thenReturn(...` using mockito and robolectric?

Comment: Looks like you will need power mockito and then mock static class

Answer (score 1):

To mock a static method or class, you have to use PowerMock, and is a bit tricky to use it with Robolectric.

You can try this here:
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/Using-PowerMock